# Calling finish() doesn't finish the activity

Tags: android, onpause, activity-finish

I want to finish my activity when it pauses for specific reasons. Up till recently my code was working perfectly but recently the `finish()` method stopped doing its job for some reason. Also, when the `finish()` method is called, I get the following `LogCat`message:

```
12-31 18:01:23.445: W/ActivityManager(481): Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{42465370 u11 "myapplicationpackage"}
```

Could someone help me out with this?

**`OnPause()` method**

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: calling finish() inside onPause is not a good idea. you can call finish() at "Specific reasons" occurrences. May in event handling etc.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this code which shows you the condition at which "Duplicate Finish Request happens".  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/com/android/server/am/ActivityStack.java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check if your activity is finishing already by calling `if (isFinishing()){}`, and calling `finish` only if it is not. <s>Alternatively you might want to specify `android:noHistory="true"` on your activity in manifest file, which will actually finish your activity once user navigates away from it.</s>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020205/android-how-to-know-if-a-fragment-has-finished-loading-entire-content

Answer (score -7):

You most possibly have duplicate copies of an activity running. I suggest make all activities under one parent, and use

```
finishall()
```

Comment: There is no method finishall.