# Android: How to know if a Fragment has finished loading entire content?

Tags: android, background, android-fragments, loading, onresume

Is there anyway to know that a `Fragment` has finish loading the entire contents of the `Fragment`?

The reason I'm asking is because in the `onResume` state when I put the application in the background I Re-Load the `Fragment` by executing an `AsyncTask` but I only want to Re-Load the `Fragment` that was put in the background only if the `Fragment` has not finished loading the entire contents of the layout (images, shapes, data, etc...)

is there anyway to know if the `Fragment` has been fully loaded?

Comment: What are you reloading? The only thing the fragment knows about is its own layout. If you are loading something else (such as information from a database) with your AsyncTask, then you need to implement your own way to telling whether that task has completed.

Comment: @Karakuri How do I know that the fragment has finished loading the entire contents of the layout?

Comment: When it returns from onCreateView, it has finished creating its layout.

Answer (score 7):

If u just want to know when your Fragment layout is fully inflated u might want to use `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` that is called after `onCreate` and `onCreateView`.
You can find more information about `Fragment` life-cycle [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Anyway, if u want more accurate answer post some of your code and make and example to better describe your purpose.